# Trying to understand how to conditionally write out element/attributes with LIINQToXML

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

This is the first time that I created a XML document using LINQToXML.
I am trying to understand how can I conditionally create attributes(or elements) when creating my document?
In this example a given car may/may not have a feature to it, so in that case I would not want to create that element, I also may have certain attributes in the feature node that could be missing.  
How could I handle these scenarios?

```
 XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(
                new XElement("root", 
                    new XElement("NodeA"),   
                    new XElement("Cars", 
                        from p in listCars
                        select new XElement("Car", new XAttribute("name", p.CarName),
                            new XElement("Feature", new XAttribute("door", p.Door), new XAttribute("model", p.Model))
                            )
                        )
                )
                );
```

Desired result #1 (All features are missing for a given car):

```
<root>
    <NodeA />
    <Cars>
        <Car name="Honda">      
            <Feature door="4" model="Accord"  />
        </Car>
        <Car name="Ford" />     
    </Cars>
</root>
```

Desired result #2 (Some features could exist)

```
<root>
    <NodeA />
    <Cars>
        <Car name="Honda">      
            <Feature door="4" model="Accord"  />
        </Car>
        <Car name="Ford">       
            <Feature model="Focus"  />
        </Car>
    </Cars>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 seperate solutions in here. Either use a method to create the features node, or do it all in one:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listCars = new List<Car>();
        listCars.Add(new Car { CarName = "test 1", Door = "0", Model = "" });
        listCars.Add(new Car { CarName = "test 2", Door = "", Model = "" });
        listCars.Add(new Car { CarName = "test 3", Door = "0", Model = "0" });

        XDocument xDoc2 = new XDocument(
               new XElement("root",
                   new XElement("NodeA"),
                   new XElement("Cars",
                       from p in listCars
                       select new XElement("Car",
                           new XAttribute("name", p.CarName),
                           p.Door != "" || p.Model != "" ? 
                            new XElement("Feature",
                                p.Door != "" ? new XAttribute("door", p.Door) : null,
                                p.Model != "" ? new XAttribute("model", p.Model) : null) : null
                           )
                       )
               )
               );


        XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(
               new XElement("root",
                   new XElement("NodeA"),
                   new XElement("Cars",
                       from p in listCars
                       select new XElement("Car",
                           new XAttribute("name", p.CarName),
                           CreateFeature(p)
                           )
                       )
               )
               );
    }

    static XElement CreateFeature(Car p)
    {
        var el = new XElement("Feature",
            p.Door != "" ? new XAttribute("door", p.Door) : null,
            p.Model != "" ? new XAttribute("model", p.Model) : null);
        return !el.Attributes().Any() ? null : el;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for both examples! I can understand better (especially with the second example) how to accomplish this task as well as other scenarios I may encounter.

Answer (score 1):

If you supply `null` instead of an element, it will be ignored, so you can use constructs like the following.

```
p.CarName != null ? new XAttribute("name", p.CarName) : null
```

If you're using C# 6, you can use null propagation.